# get gradle dependency for class

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I have a sample Project which has lots of dependencies (over 100).

The sample references a class which I need in my project.

How to find the gradle dependency which is providing this class?

Comment: Ctrl+Click the class name. The class source code opens and you will see in the breadcrumb navigation bar the name of the jar it is contained in (and also in the AndroidStudio window title).

Comment: Nice. Thx for the easy solution. Just wondering if there is a built-in way like a gradle cmd to find that. Anyway If you post this as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control click on the class then assure that `Autoscroll from source` is selected.
[image]
That will bring you to something similar:

[image]

That will give you he name of the dependency in the build.gradle file.

The screenshots are from IntelliJ but the behaviour should be the same on Android Studio.